# How to register a pyrogram account

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I'm trying to signup on `telegram` using `pyrogram` library

Here's the code I used

```
sc = app.send_code(phone_number = phone)

app.sign_up(
        phone_number = phone,
        phone_code_hash = code,
        first_name  = first_name,
        last_name = last_name
    )
```

I get below error

`pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.PhoneCodeExpired: [400 PHONE_CODE_EXPIRED]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are registering `telegram` account not `pyrogram` account.
Also, you should tell what variables you have.

You forgot why you called `send_code` function in the first place.

This would work

```
sent_code = app.send_code(phone_number=phone)

app.sign_up(
        phone_number = phone,
        phone_code_hash = sent_code.phone_code_hash,
        first_name  = first_name,
        last_name = last_name
)
```

Comment: please share full code .